# How can I shut off the water to my toilet?

Tags: plumbing, water, shutoff

I'm trying to install a bidet in my apartment and I don't see a water shut-off valve. Or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] so you know how to respond to answers. "Thanks" comments are discouraged.

Comment: When you figure out how to shut off the water, please replace this 90 degree adapter with a [dual shutoff valve](https://www.bing.com/search?q=dual+shut+off+supply+stop) so that if something goes wrong with the bidet you can turn it off and still flush the toilet.

Comment: Prepare to have an aneurysm if you click the link in the comment above.

Comment: @user169996 Note that comments aren't always in a consistent order, so "the comment above" isn't very useful

Answer (score 8):

Your picture shows that there is no water shutoff valve in the toilet water line.

If you have a separate water meter for your apartment, there could be a shutoff valve right after the meter. If the handle turns easily, turn it off, open the sink faucet to release water pressure, then remove the flexible toilet water pipe and add the bidet attachments. You can also add a water shutoff valve to the toilet supply pipe at the wall, to make repairs easier in the future. Some rags or dirty clothes under the water line can soak up dripping water. (Note: if the handle for the water meter valve does not turn easily, don't turn it off, it is probably jammed. Turning it harder will probably break it. You'll have to involve your landlord in the fix.)

It is possible there is no main water shutoff valve for your apartment. Some apartments only have main water shutoffs for the whole building. If you can't find it, you may have to ask your landlord to turn the water off.

Note, it may be a problem with your lease to add items to the water system. The landlord will likely let you know if a plumber has to install this for you to remain in compliance with your lease.

Comment: @Sravya It's also possible that your toilet is on a different water system (using captured rain water) So the main shutoff for your apartment might not shut off the water to the toilet. Then it's debatable whether that non-potable water is clean enough to wash your privates with.

Comment: Are there really apartments where fixing a leaky toilet valve requires shutting down the whole building?   IT wouldn't surprise me, I'm just wondering if you've actually seen it.  Geez.

Comment: I haven't seen it personally, but I saw a video where a poor guy was trying to get a valve back on the hot water pipe under a bathroom sink, and couldn't do it. Water was gushing almost fire-hose strength from under the cabinet, and washed out a couple apartments. The description said the apartment complex had only one cutoff for several buildings.

Comment: @jay613 - my daughter's condo building is that way - really stupid of course. I think they can shut off by floor, not the whole building.

Answer (score 4):

In theory you can freeze the pipe where the hose to the toilet connects, disconnect it, and add a proper connection with a shutoff valve like any properly installed toilet should have. Of course, if this messes up and the freeze plug doesn't hold, you'll have a gigantic mess and probably be responsible for damages. Since it's an apartment, the only really reasonable course of action is to contact the property owner/manager to figure out how they want it done. If that's not an option for some reason, then you have risk assessment to do...

Another option to consider: there's no reason the water for the bidet has to come from the toilet hookup. If you have access to run a hose from under the sink, and if the water lines under the sink have cutoff valves to service the faucets, you could just hook it up there instead.